# Purge a "x" number of messages of a user or amount in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

**Error**

My purge command given below deletes all messages in a channel when I use `!purge 10`. I'm not sure about the error and how to fix it.

**Code**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    args: true,
    usage: '<@user> <number> `or` <number>',
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord){
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        const number = !!parseInt(args[0]) ? parseInt(args[0]) : parseInt(args[1]);

        if(isNaN(number)){
            return message.reply('Enter a valid number. Eg: `!purge 10`')
        };

        if(number > 99 || number < 1){
            return message.reply('Cannot clear messages more than `100` and less than `1`')
        };
        
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({
            limit: 100,
        }).then((messages) =>{
            if(user){
                const purge = user ? user.id : client.user.id;

                messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === purge).array().slice(0, number)
            }

        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true).catch(console.error)
        });

        await message.channel.send(`\`${number}\` message(s) cleared!`).then(m =>{
            m.delete({timeout: 3000})
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: No error, it just deletes all messages in a channel, while I just want to delete the given amount

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a **specific** amount of messages, you have to use the [`<textChannel>.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) function.

For example:

```js
const messagesToDelete = args[0];
<textChannel>.bulkDelete(messagesToDelete)
  .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I'm bulk deleting the messages in my code, the problem is, it deletes all messages while the input is only `10`.